# Running Maven inside a Cloud9 Docker container

Tags: maven, docker, cloud9-ide, docker-machine, cloud9

I am figuring out how to run Maven inside a Cloud9 workspace's console inside a Docker container running on Docker VM on a Mac.

The problem is that the `apt-get` command is not able to resolve any of the packages that it normally would, as the Docker VM contains a minimal Linux distribution:

```
# apt-get install maven                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package maven
```

It is a public image from Docker Hub. The only solution to this seems to be creating a custom container (running `docker commit`, doing some changes to Dockerfile...), but both seem quite combersome to repeat this `docker commit` every time a minor dependency needs to be updated...

What would be the best way to run the `mvn` command inside a Docker container?

Answer (score 2):

You need the following:

```
# apt-get update          
# apt-get install maven
```

`apt-get update` is used to get the package cache.

Comment: It works, but after restarting the container the updates get lost.

Comment: @PeterGerhat Can you commit the container after running the maven install and start the new container.

Comment: @PeterGerhat Can you accept the answer - if it satisfied your requirement.